# Is /dev/shm faster than /tmp?

Tags: linux, memory, performance

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/45342) queries whether to use `/dev/shm` or `/tmp`. Within the answers provided, the general impression arises that `/dev/shm` is faster than `/tmp` since it writes to RAM instead of disc. Searching the webs about this topic vaguely confirms this impression. Unfortunately, I can't find a reliable source undoubtedly showing which one is more performant, e.g. by measurement.

For example, this quote from the first answer:

> Since RAM is significantly faster than disk storage, you can [use
> /dev/shm instead of /tmp for the performance boost](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html), if your process is
> I/O intensive and extensively uses temporary files.

The linked article states:

> /dev/shm is nothing but implementation of traditional shared memory
> concept. It is an efficient means of passing data between programs.
> One program will create a memory portion, which other processes (if
> permitted) can access. This will result into speeding up things on
> Linux.

This does neither confirm the answer citing this web site, nor does it compare the performance of `/dev/shm` vs. `/tmp`. It is rather a mere description of what `/dev/shm` is.

Nonetheless, there is one [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp#comment752987_45509) in the first answer, stating (as of today):

> There is no performance boost by using /dev/shm. /dev/shm is memory
> (tmpfs) backed by the disk (swap). /var/tmp is memory (disk cache)
> backed by the disk (on-disk filesystem). In practice, performance is
> about the same (tmpfs has a slight edge but not enough to matter).
> /tmp may be tmpfs or not depending on how the administrator configured
> it. There is no good reason to use /dev/shm in your scripts.

As this comment remains unchallenged, and other answers and comments suggest otherwise, the question remains whether `/dev/shm` is faster than `/tmp` or not?

NB: I'm well aware that the answer most probably is like "it depends". There is [a question here on SU:SE](https://superuser.com/q/943827/1192744) about which filesystem to use for `/tmp`. There is also a [related question over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9745281/7431523).

Comment: Is your question about tmpfs vs on-disk filesystems in general, or about the specific /dev/shm tmpfs instance vs other tmpfs instances?

Comment: It's about the latter. How to improve the wording to make that clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `/dev/shm` you are not writing directly RAM. It is a *tmpfs* filesystem, *tmpfs* keeps all files in virtual memory (a disk as an extension of RAM).

From [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/filesystems/tmpfs.html):

> If you compare it to ramfs (which was the template to create tmpfs) you gain swapping and limit checking. Another similar thing is the RAM disk (/dev/ram*), which simulates a fixed size hard disk in physical RAM, where you have to create an ordinary filesystem on top. Ramdisks cannot swap and you do not have the possibility to resize them.
>
> Since tmpfs lives completely in the page cache and on swap, all tmpfs
> pages will be shown as “Shmem” in /proc/meminfo and “Shared” in
> free(1). Notice that these counters also include shared memory (shmem,
> see ipcs(1)). The most reliable way to get the count is using df(1)
> and du(1).

[ramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.html) is a RAM-based filesystem:

> Ramfs is a very simple filesystem that exports Linux’s disk caching mechanisms (the page cache and dentry cache) as a dynamically resizable RAM-based filesystem.

Therefore, answering to your question, there is not a performance boost since both (/dev/shm and /tmp) are using the disk.

You can verify when you write in RAM with this example:

```
mkdir /mnt/ram
mount -t ramfs -o size=2g ramfs /mnt/ram
# Create random file of 2GB
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=2000000 of=/tmp/testfile conv=notrunc
# Check ram usage
free
cp /tmp/testfile /mnt/ram
# Check ram usage again
free
```

Comment: Virtual memory is not just "a disk as an extension of RAM", is it? It maps program addresses either to ram or to swap, paging in and out as needed. So `/dev/shm` should be using more RAM and less disk than `/tmp`, which only uses the disk. Which should be a slight performance boost.